# Images won't co-ordinate in sync between two blocks when using a keyframe image rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nearly good working code for a double layer image slider. I've tentatively created 2 independent but identical image sliders where an image slides in & out of view over top of a background of cycling images but the background images won't co-ordinate in sync on both image blocks. Sure could use some help with this.

Below is a snippet based on my code:

```js
function cycleBackgrounds() {
  var index = 0;

  $imageEls = $('.toggle-image'); // Get the images to be cycled.

  setInterval(function() {
    // Get the next index.  If at end, restart to the beginning.
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    // Show the next image.
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    // Hide the previous image.
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');

  }, 10000);
};

// Document Ready.
$(function() {
  cycleBackgrounds();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000
}
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 100px 0px;
}
.slideshow1 {
  width: 104px;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 219px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slid_1,
.slid_2,
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
}
.slid_1 {
  left: 0;
}
.slid_2 {
  left: 104px;
}
.slide1 {
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: anim_slide1;
  -moz-animation-duration: 20s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: anim_slide1;
  -ms-animation-duration: 20s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-name: anim_slide1;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: anim_slide1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slide1 {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slide1 {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim_slide1 {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes anim_slide1 {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
.slideshow {
  width: 104px;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 219px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slid_1,
.slid_2,
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
}
.slid_1 {
  left: 0;
}
.slid_2 {
  left: 104px;
}
.slide {
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: anim_slide;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: anim_slide;
  -ms-animation-duration: 10s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-name: anim_slide;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: anim_slide;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slide {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slide {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim_slide {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes anim_slide {
  0% {
    left:0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
/* Styles for the alternating / transition effect. */

.toggle-image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:219px;
  transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
/* Styles for the specific images. */

.first-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/OfhfhHNr42EQE_jVr3sM.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.second-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/Q1bqSCICZHlq5KP4jLCI.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.third-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/v_8VBpL9eMq_hS4JFyp_.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.first-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
.second-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
.third-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
/* Styles for the alternating / transition effect. */

.toggles-image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:219px;
  transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
      <div class="slideshow1">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <div class="slide1">
          <!--<![endif]-->
          <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" />
        </div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
      <div class="slideshow1">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
        <div class="slide1">
          <!--<![endif]-->
          <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" />
        </div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Bobxzx/pen/NNWzaQ) and to see what I'm trying to apply it to in it's existing form now, you can view [on my site](http://hotrockcentralpage.proboards.com).

Comment: Why do you have 2 jquery references in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** (Short answer)

It is because of how your JS is written. When you get the image elements using the below statement, you are basically getting all the elements with `class = 'toggle-image'` in the page and there are six such elements (three in the first slideshow `div` and three in the second).

```
$imageEls = $('.toggle-image');
```

So, your loop is effectively working from 0 to 5 instead of from 0 to 2 and this is causing the images to get out of sync.

---

**Long Answer: Why were the images out of sync in both blocks?**

The below is your HTML structure and for purpose of explanation, I have added the index number of each image element next to it (as a comment):

```
<div class="slideshow1">
  <div class="slide1">
    <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" />
  </div>
  <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div> <!-- index = 0 -->
  <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div> <!-- index = 1 -->
  <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div> <!-- index = 2 -->
</div>
<!-- stripped out code irrelevant to answer -->
<div class="slideshow1">
  <div class="slide1">
    <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" /> </div>
  <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div> <!-- index = 3 -->
  <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div> <!-- index = 4 -->
  <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div> <!-- index = 5 -->
</div>
```

Now lets see how the loop (via the `setInterval`) actually works. But before we do that, note that the image elements with index as 0 and 3 (that is, first image under both slideshow `div`) are visible upon page load because they have `class='show'` added manually in the HTML.

```
Interval No  | Index 0   | Index 1   | Index 2   | Index 3    | Index 4   | Index 5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Page load)  | Visible   | Invisible | Invisible | Visible   | Invisible | Invisible 
1st Interval | Invisible | Visible   | Invisible | Visible   | Invisible | Invisible
2nd Interval | Invisible | Invisible | Visible   | Visible   | Invisible | Invisible
3rd Interval | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Visible   | Invisible | Invisible
4th Interval | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Visible   | Invisible
5th Interval | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Invisible | Visible
```

As you can see from above table there is an obvious disconnect in terms of the image that is visible.

---

**What is the solution?**

What you actually need to do is get  the number of `imageEls` under each slideshow `div` (or just get the total and divide by two like I have done) and hide/show the element(s) corresponding to the index number under each slideshow `div` instead of using the global document level index.

```
function cycleBackgrounds() {
  var index = 0;
  $slideShows = $('.slideshow1');
  $imageEls = $('.toggle-image'); // Get the images to be cycled.

  setInterval(function() {

    // Get the next index.  If at end, restart to the beginning.
    // Since we are dividing it by 2, the loop would only go from index = 0 to 2.
    index = index + 1 < ($imageEls.length / 2) ? index + 1 : 0;

    // Show the next image corresponding to the index under each slideshow
    $slideShows.each(function() {
      $(this).children('.toggle-image').eq(index).addClass('show');
      // Hide the previous image.
      $(this).children('.toggle-image').eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');
    });
  }, 10000);
};
```

**Demo:** (I have removed a lot of repetitive, unnecessary code and browser prefixed versions)

```js
function cycleBackgrounds() {
  var index = 0;
  $slideShows = $('.slideshow1');
  $imageEls = $('.toggle-image');

  setInterval(function() {
    index = index + 1 < ($imageEls.length / 2) ? index + 1 : 0;
    $slideShows.each(function() {
      $(this).children('.toggle-image').eq(index).addClass('show');
      $(this).children('.toggle-image').eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');
    });
  }, 10000);
};

$(function() {
  cycleBackgrounds();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000
}
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 100px 0px;
}
.slideshow1 {
  width: 104px;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 219px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slid_1,
.slid_2,
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
}
.slid_1 {
  left: 0;
}
.slid_2 {
  left: 104px;
}
.slide1 {
  width: 104px;
  height: 219px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: anim_slide1;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes anim_slide1 {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  21% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  29% {
    left: 105px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  71% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  79% {
    left: -105px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

/* Styles for the alternating / transition effect. */

.toggle-image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:219px;
  transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

/* Styles for the specific images. */

.first-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/OfhfhHNr42EQE_jVr3sM.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.second-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/Q1bqSCICZHlq5KP4jLCI.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.third-image {
  background-image:url('http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/v_8VBpL9eMq_hS4JFyp_.gif');
  background-size:104px 219px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.first-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
.second-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
.third-image.show {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="slideshow1">
        <div class="slide1">
          <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" />
        </div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="slideshow1">
        <div class="slide1">
          <img src="http://s16879.storage.proboards.com/6436879/i/ihfBlEhkcXWqZh3B8tOm.gif" width="104px" height="219px" />
        </div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image first-image show"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image second-image"></div>
        <div class="background-image toggle-image third-image"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, I bow to you....looks & works awesome & thx again for the assist!